# Create a record based on the string class name

Tags: clojure, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to create an event store where I have a table somewhat like this:

```clj
CREATE TABLE domain_events (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  timestamp timestamptz,
  entity_id int,
  type text,
  data jsonb
);
```

And I have a namespace like

```clj
(ns my-domain.domain-events)

(defrecord PurchaseOrderCreated
  [id timestamp purchase-order-id created-by])

(defrecord PurchaseOrderCancelled
  [id timestamp purchase-order-id cancelled-by])
```

So `type` is a string name for the fully qualified class name, something like `my_domain.domain_events.PurchaseOrderCreated`, which comes from getting the `type` from a record e.g. `(type (->PurchaseOrderCreated))`. I should note that `(type the-event)` actually produces a string prefixed with `class`  such as `class my_domain.domain_events.PurchaseOrderCreaated` so I am trimming this off before storing in the DB.

I'm trying to figure out how I can retrieve these event rows from the database and rehydrate them to domain events. I feel like I'm close but just haven't been able to get all the pieces.

I've tried to use `new` to construct a new record but I seem to have a hard time converting the string classname to a record.

```clj
(new (resolve (symbol "my_domain.domain_events.PurchaseOrderCreated")) prop1 prop2 ...)
```

Plus I'm not sure how easy it's going to be to use `new` since my `array-of-properties` is going to need to be in the correct order. It may be better to use the `map->PurchaseOrderCreated` but I'm still not sure how to dynamically resolve this constructor based on the string classname.

Can anybody advise on what the best approach would be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work but I'm not show if there's a more idiomatic way for it:

```
((resolve (symbol "my_domain.domain_events"
                  (str "map->"
                       "PurchaseOrderCreated")))
 {:id 123})
```

`symbol` takes can take a `ns`:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol

Comment: That did somewhat work! Only thing I had to change was the namespace needed to be hyphenated instead of underscorized, but it did work. I am curious to know if there is another way but this unblocked me, thanks!